# Sheet dismisses itself when pressing return on keyboard after invoking the sheet from a Menu View

Tags: swift, swiftui

I finally managed to code a minimally reproducible example. I have a simple list that shows 100 items. Each row has a menu view. Scroll to the 99th row, press the edit button which brings up a menu view and press the edit button in that menu view.

Press on the textfield to bring up the keyboard and hit return on the keyboard. The sheet dismisses itself. This DOES NOT HAPPEN on the upper rows of the list list. Generally in the bottom rows.

On the 97th row, just tapping on the textfield is enough for the sheet to dismiss itself.

Extremely easy to happen on both the simulator and an actual device.

Tried the following that didn't work:

- Interactive disabled modifier
- Using the other sheet modifier variant which takes in an item
- Replaced sheet with full screen cover
- FocusState property wrapper and its related modifiers

Anyone knows how to fix this?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List(0..<100) { number in
            HStack {
                Text("\(number)")
                
                Spacer()
                
                MenuView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MenuView: View {
    @State private var showingSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Menu {
            Button("Edit") {
                showingSheet = true
            }
        } label: {
            Label("Edit", systemImage: "pencil")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
            SheetView()
        }
    }
}

struct SheetView: View {
    @State private var text = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView {
                TextField("Name", text: $text)
                    .padding()
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm anyone? Does no one knows how to fix this?

Comment: What if you show the sheet from `ContentView` instead of `MenuView`?

Answer (score 0):

Add this `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)` in ContentView something like this

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    List(0..<100) { number in
        HStack {
            Text("\(number)")
            Spacer()
            MenuView()
        }
    }
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)   << Here
  }
}
```

i have checked it's working fine as expected for me, here is your Full code

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    List(0..<100) { number in
        HStack {
            Text("\(number)")
            
            Spacer()
            
            MenuView()
        }
    }
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
 }
}

struct MenuView: View {
 @State private var showingSheet = false

var body: some View {
    Menu {
        Button("Edit") {
            showingSheet = true
        }
    } label: {
        Label("Edit", systemImage: "pencil")
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
        SheetView()
    }
   }
 }

struct SheetView: View {
@State private var text = ""

var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        ScrollView {
            TextField("Name", text: $text)
                .padding()
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
        }
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
 static var previews: some View {
     ContentView()
 }
}
```